# Can I use open Sourced Sagemaker-Neo (neo-ai-dlr) Externally on platform other than AWS?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, amazon-sagemaker, inference

My question is about sagemaker neo which was open sourced as neo-ai-dlr.
Can i use it externally on my trained model on platform other than AWS like my local machine?

Any Help would be appreciated
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [neo-ai-dlr](https://github.com/neo-ai/neo-ai-dlr) can be used out of AWS, see supported devices here: https://neo-ai-dlr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html